# Нет доступа у nginx к сокету (Nginx + uWSGI + Flask) как настроить верно?

Tags: nginx, flask, fedora, uwsgi

При запросе к странице http://127.0.0.1:8080/ получаю ответ от nginx 502 bad gateway.

Просматривая логи `/var/log/nginx/error.log` вижу что, нет доступа к сокету:

`unix:///run/uwsgi/server.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///run/uwsgi/server.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"`

Права на сокет `ls -l server.sock`:

`srw-rw-r--. 1 zavod zavod 0 мар 30 11:43 server.sock`

Принудительно меняя `sudo chown zavod:nginx server.sock` или группу и пользователя `sudo chown nginx:nginx server.sock` результата не дает и ответ тот же Permession Denied.

Сокет запускаю вирутуальном окружении по команде `uwsgi --ini conf2.ini` и с сокетом, вроде, все в порядке.
Содержимое конфигурации для запуска `/home/zavod/uchet3/conf2.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

chdir = /home/zavod/uchet3
home = /home/zavod/uchet3/venv

master = true
processes = 5
socket = /run/uwsgi/server.sock
chmod-socket = 664
uid = zavod
gid = nginx
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Конфигурация `/etc/nginx/conf.d/uchet_nginx.conf`:

```
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        
        location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi/server.sock; 
        include uwsgi_params;
       }
    }
```

Сам nginx, запущен от пользователя nginx и конфигурация добавлена через директиву include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; в разделе http {}.
Часть содержимого `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user nginx;
http {
...
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Может быть не в той папке запускаю или nginx не от того пользователя запущен, может быть что-то не так с ini uwsgi файла?

Система Fedora 31

Answer (score 0):

При выполнении команды

> setenforce 0

Все заработало